# Error in vector file

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have an error like this in my project.

```
 error C2036: 'ClassName *' : unknown size  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector   735
```

There are a lot of places in the code like `std::vector<ClassName>` is used, so I am a little confused what is the possible reason of this error.

In some classes I return such vectors from methods like

```
class AnotherClass
{
    public:
    std::vector<ClassName> AnotherClass::GetVector()
    {
        return _myVector;
    }
    private:
    std::vector<ClassName> _myVector;
};
```

Is it a possible reason? Or there is another common mistake that leads to this error?

Comment: **Oops! You forgot to present your [testcase](http://sscce.org).**

Comment: Does the file containing the above method include the file that contain the body of `class ClassName`?

Comment: Why are you using `AnotherClass::GetVector()` inside the `AnotherClass` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a matter of forgetting to include the header file that contains the declaration of ClassName